# 5.1 Sound on Encore ENM232-6VIA

Tags: 10.10, sound, drivers, hardware, soundcard

Only front right and left speaker work, and my 5.1 card, is recognized by Ubuntu 10.10, but I have no option for 5.1 in the profile combo **Sound** -> **Hardware**

I have tried `default-sample-channels = 6` without success.

**This is lshw output:**

```
*-multimedia  
   description: Multimedia audio controller  
   product: VT1720/24 [Envy24PT/HT] PCI Multi-Channel Audio Controller  
   vendor: VIA Technologies Inc.  
   physical id: 8  
   bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0  
   version: 01  
   width: 32 bits  
   clock: 33MHz  
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list  
   configuration: driver=ICE1724 latency=32  
   resources: irq:17 ioport:f800(size=32) ioport:f400(size=128)
```

I have searched up and down for a solution with no luck:

**Found something else**, sound comes out from 3 jacks but they all have the same left and right channel. Also one of the jacks is supposed to be line-in.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try unmuting the Rear, Center and LFE using the advanced volume or alsamixer ?

In Ubuntu the only applications that I know to be able to use 5.1 channels are:

Alsa - driver - needs to be unmuted

Amarok - needs to be configured (in graphical options)

Pulseaudio - mixer - needs to be configured (edit a text file in root)

Totem - needs to be configured - (in graphical options)

speaker-test - perfect

Alsa is automatically configured for 5.1 channels - test this with (after unmuting):

speaker-test -Dplug:surround51 -c6 -l2

where "-c6" means six channels, and "-l2" means run the test twice.

To test pulseaudio, open Totem or Amarok configured to play a DTS file and open:

pavumeter

Watch and see if the sounds are distinct on every channel.

Comment: Yes I did. When using speaker-test only front and rear worked.

Comment: Pulseaudio has some other options in the configuration file regarding center and LFE/subwoofer. Try some combinations.

Comment: Also to fix the same left and right channel try to disable all checks that have the word "mixer" in their name in alsamixer (or the advanced control settings - Options - Show *mixer* - Uncheck them).

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with this soundcard, only the right channel works with boths (speakers & headphones). My speakers are not for 5.1. :S

Comment: Are you using 10.10? In my case both channels worked. The problem was that 3 jacks have right an left

Answer (score 0):

Try updating alsa It will recognize your sound card,or try your vendors web site and get support for your matter. If given, use their drivers and install carefully after reading the READ ME! (you will make your sounds completely gone if you do something wrong there-Self experience)