# No sound in Ubuntu 13.10, tried everything

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I've read through a bunch of differen't suggestions.  I've restarted/rebuilt alsa as well as pulse audio.  I've ran speakertest.  I've installed ubuntu restricted extras.  Here's what's happening...

When I first boot to ubuntu it says something along the lines of

```
intel hda : no codecs found
```

When I try running hdajackretask at the top it says

```
No codecs found.  Sorry.
```

The sound button in the top right menu bar is now gone (I think I broke that by trying to fix everything)

My sound card is Encore Electronics ENM232-8VIA

When I open up 'Sound' in 'System Settings' it shows 1 digital out, and then 2 other outputs (one amplified, one not) which I believe are my actual sound card outputs.

Any help would be great... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your sound card manufacturer has failed so far to release a Linux driver. From what I have read on different linux forums there is some other driver for another sound card that could be compatible with yours. It looks like the ice1724 driver for the Envy24HT will work for your card in Ubuntu if you have VIA VT1723 chipset present on your sound card.

This is just [a list of linux drivers](http://www.filewatcher.com/_/?q=ice1724) for Ice1724, and you can check your kernel version, and also your Ubuntu architecture (32bit or 64 bit) and try to find some version of Ice1724 which is compatible with your system. Even if you find it, I am not sure it will work but this is the best I could do since there is no linux driver available for your sound card.

There is a similar problem with yours [on this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8380/5-1-sound-on-encore-enm232-6via), and maybe you can use some of the answers and suggestions in there to solve your own problem.